# Is there any real alternative to GeoServer as dynamic map generator in Java?

Tags: java, geoserver

I'm looking for the most suitable tool for generating dynamic geographical maps in Java (with styles based on custom business data: colors, labels etc. will be dynamically set). After some searching, only GeoServer (and the underlying GeoTools library) seems to fit.

Although I'm really happy with this solution, I'm afraid I might miss something and make some decision based on incomplete input. Any suggestion ? Any viable alternative to compare against ?

Comment: Are you looking for a web map server or will a desktop GIS do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [OpenMap](http://openmap-java.org/). It is a descent alternative to manipulate/display geospatial data.

Comment: Thanks ! I actually did encounter this while searching, but at a first glance it didn't seem to be as flexible and powerful as GeoServer. I'll have a closer look.

Comment: OpenMap is completely different to GeoServer with completely different list of features. Is not an alternative. Are different software.

Comment: It is an alternative as a library for building a Java app with maps, which GeoServer could be used for, but it is not an alternative as a standalone map server. (It also seems to have stopped updating at the end of 2016.)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to check out [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/).

Both MapServer and GeoServer support OGC-compliant WMS requests, so they're basically inter-exchangeable if you use something like OpenLayers.

MapServer's got a handy installer that lets you install every aspect that you might need to get your server and web application going. It runs on Apache, which I find a big advantage over GeoServer, which runs on Jetty (it's all-java).

However, I'm now using GeoServer myself now. It's really easy to administer stuff via its web interface, and overall it just feels pretty polished. Maybe it's because I've been using it for a while now, but I just get stuff done quickly with it.

Answer (score 2):

The thread may be old but in case anyone else is looking for a similar solution it is worth checking out Nasa World Wind.
http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/

Comment: That is neat, but underneath, it is GeoServer. Still worth considering instead of maintaining all the aspects of GeoServer yourself.